# Müller's Method

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I have these question and I cannot solve it.

Can somebody help me?

> Use Müller’s method to determine the roots of
>   $$
>  f(x)=2x^5−2x^4+6x^3−6x^2+8x−8
> $$
>   Choose $x_2=0.8 $, $x_0=0.808$ $x_1=0.792$.
>
> Terminate your computation when the approximate relative error falls below  $E_s = 10^{-4}$

Comment: Do you have Müllers algorithm as some library, or code or an algorithmic description? What does your script say, what internet sources did you consult?

Comment: For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method contains a complete description. And it is David Eugene Muller of Texas and Illinois.

Comment: yeah ı know this. but ı cant solve it. ı need solution.

Comment: What do you mean? You can make an Excel table that implements this algorithm, no further programing knowledge required. What exactly is the step that you can not do? If there is no such step, why do you study this stuff, why do you waste your time, your life?

Comment: ı am civil engineer. this is my homework and ı am inadequate to solve this problem. ı need help immediately.

Comment: ı need iteration step for solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like the Wikipedia page already referenced contains a "recurrence relation" exactly like what you are looking for.  What else do you need?

Comment: how can ı get this form( a(x-x2)^2 + b(x-x2) + c ) the function

Comment: Even that is explained on the wikipedia page. For details see Newton interpolation (you can also start with Lagrange interpolation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential formulas in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method are
$$
 w = f[x_{k-1},x_{k-2}] + f[x_{k-1},x_{k-3}] - f[x_{k-2},x_{k-3}]. \, 
$$
and 
$$
x_{k} = x_{k-1} - \frac{2f(x_{k-1})}{w \pm \sqrt{w^2 - 4f(x_{k-1})f[x_{k-1}, x_{k-2}, x_{k-3}]}}. 
$$

The most difficult part is to find striking variable names... Set

- `x1` for $x_{k-1}$, `x2` for $x_{k-2}$ etc. and
- `f1=f(x1)` for `f(x_{k-1})`, `f2=f(x2)`, etc. and
- for the divided differences set

  - `f12=(f1-f2)/(x1-x2)` for $f[x_{k-1},x_{k-2}]$,
  - `f23=(f2-f3)/(x2-x3)` and
  - `f13=(f1-f3)/(x1-x3)` and finally
  - `f123=(f12-f23)/(x1-x3)` for $f[x_{k-1},x_{k-2},x_{k-3}]$

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<complex.h>

complex double f(complex double x) {
    complex double x2 = x*x;
    return (x-1)*((x2+2)*(x2+2)-x2);
}

complex double Muller(complex double (*f)(complex double), double a, double b, double c) {    
    // initialize
    unsigned int k=0;
    complex double x1 = c, f1 = f(x1);
    complex double x2 = b, f2 = f(x2), f12 = (f1-f2)/(x1-x2);
    complex double x3 = a, f3 = f(x3), f13 = (f1-f3)/(x1-x3), f23 = (f2-f3)/(x2-x3);
    complex double f123 = (f12-f23)/(x1-x3);
    double scale = fmax(cabs(f1),fmax(cabs(f2),cabs(f3)));

    printf("x[%2u]=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\tf(x[%2u])=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\n",
           k,creal(x3),cimag(x3),k,creal(f3),cimag(f3));
    k++;
    printf("x[%2u]=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\tf(x[%2u])=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\n",
           k,creal(x2),cimag(x2),k,creal(f2),cimag(f2));
    k++;
    printf("x[%2u]=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\tf(x[%2u])=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\n",
           k,creal(x1),cimag(x1),k,creal(f1),cimag(f1));
    k++;
    // loop
    double err = 1;
    while ( err > 1e-4 )
    {
        // iteration formulas, variables are type complex double, controls real
        complex double w = f12 - f23 + f13;
        complex double root = csqrt(w*w-4*f1*f123);
        if( cabs(w+root) < cabs(w-root) ) root = -root;
        complex double x0 = x1 - 2*f1/(w+root);
        complex double f0 = f(x0);
        printf("x[%2u]=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\tf(x[%2u])=%-15.12f%+15.12fi,\n",
               k,creal(x0),cimag(x0),k,creal(f0),cimag(f0));
        k++;

        // shift the index for the next step, (1,2,3) <- (0,1,2)
        x3=x2; x2=x1; x1=x0;
        f3=f2; f2=f1; f1=f0;
        f23 = f12;

        // recompute remaining divided differences
        f12 = (f1-f2)/(x1-x2); f13 = (f1-f3)/(x1-x3);
        f123 = (f12-f23)/(x1-x3);

        // finish by computing control variables
        err = fmin( cabs(f1)/scale, cabs(x2-x1)/fabs(b-a) );
    }
    return x1;
}

int main() {
    Muller(*f, 0.808, 0.792, 0.8);
    printf("\n\nRestart\n\n");
    Muller(*f, -0.808, -0.792, -0.8);
    printf("\n\nRestart\n\n");
    Muller(*f, -1.808, -1.792, -1.8);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Log of the computation

```
x[ 0]=0.808000000000 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 0])=-1.225886093279+0.000000000000i,
x[ 1]=0.792000000000 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 1])=-1.305252442145+0.000000000000i,
x[ 2]=0.800000000000 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 2])=-1.265920000000+0.000000000000i,
x[ 3]=1.007594143502 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 3])=0.061333813157 +0.000000000000i,
x[ 4]=0.999691840144 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 4])=-0.002464329484+0.000000000000i,
x[ 5]=0.999999517022 +0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 5])=-0.000003863821+0.000000000000i,


Restart

x[ 0]=-0.808000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 0])=-11.543760711713+0.000000000000i,
x[ 1]=-0.792000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 1])=-11.245251809247+0.000000000000i,
x[ 2]=-0.800000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 2])=-11.393280000000+0.000000000000i,
x[ 3]=-0.313139488169-0.597993095065i,  f(x[ 3])=-3.578785212716-3.102850582564i,
x[ 4]=-0.152423434021-0.896568995507i,  f(x[ 4])=-2.174496945609-2.419209170588i,
x[ 5]=-0.113762245198-1.283180404737i,  f(x[ 5])=-1.974140842175-2.072205685530i,
x[ 6]=-0.590242127121-1.562744397202i,  f(x[ 6])=-1.355281768619+5.516580476110i,
x[ 7]=-0.451736511236-1.277417823451i,  f(x[ 7])=-0.401351555157-0.782834069193i,
x[ 8]=-0.493961290160-1.317349685898i,  f(x[ 8])=-0.054707398842-0.107598547954i,
x[ 9]=-0.499942023498-1.322680432217i,  f(x[ 9])=0.000220582660 -0.003039079565i,
x[10]=-0.500000033538-1.322875803330i,  f(x[10])=-0.000000312546+0.000002246640i,


Restart

x[ 0]=-1.808000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 0])=-68.773715292193+0.000000000000i,
x[ 1]=-1.792000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 1])=-66.857255669727+0.000000000000i,
x[ 2]=-1.800000000000+0.000000000000i,  f(x[ 2])=-67.809280000000+0.000000000000i,
x[ 3]=-1.182333251904-0.563769729100i,  f(x[ 3])=-10.589662224283-18.750119777722i,
x[ 4]=-0.933263172300-0.753306592649i,  f(x[ 4])=-2.028773338306-12.084168632225i,
x[ 5]=-0.707684635587-0.951498316047i,  f(x[ 5])=0.866873722369 -6.119938934357i,
x[ 6]=-0.547056458429-1.156597078482i,  f(x[ 6])=0.791543009771 -2.225497123247i,
x[ 7]=-0.493379197649-1.278355700046i,  f(x[ 7])=0.097313082739 -0.629785563704i,
x[ 8]=-0.496959319137-1.320479889960i,  f(x[ 8])=-0.029703785932-0.049268561946i,
x[ 9]=-0.499969027836-1.322900955102i,  f(x[ 9])=-0.000567484947+0.000190261047i,
```

Check:
$$
2x^5−2x^4+6x^3−6x^2+8x−8=2(x-1)(x^4+3x^2+4)=2(x-1)((x^2+2)^2-x^2)\\
=2(x-1)(x^2-x+2)(x^2+x+2)
$$
with roots $1$ and $\pm\frac12\pm i·\frac{\sqrt{7}}2$, independent signs for 4 roots.

Comment: thank you LutzL. is that solution for matlab?

Comment: No, this is incomplete C code. In matlab you might want to store the iterates in a stack to display them later.

Comment: can you give me complete C code?

Comment: No, I just constructed this, it is as yet untested.

Comment: it is useless for me in this condition but thank you much for your patience. as ı said ı need solution